# ORM (esp. NHibernate) performance for complex queries

Tags: .net, performance, nhibernate, orm

My company is in the process of rewriting an existing application from scratch. This application, among other tasks, performs complex SQL queries against order and invoice data to produce sales reports. The queries are built dynamically depending on which criteria are selected by the user, so they can be pretty complex if many criteria are selected. Currently, performance is decent, but not great.

Now, for the new version, we would like to use an ORM, probably NHibernate because it's apparently the only one that supports Oracle Lite (the application uses either Oracle or Oracle Lite, depending on whether it's running in connected or disconnected mode). But I'm worried about the performance of queries generated by NHibernate. I've worked with other ORMs before (Linq to SQL, Entity Framework), but the queries were pretty simple, so there was no performance issue.

So, before I take a decision about using an ORM or staying with plain SQL, I'd like to know how well these tools handle scenarios such as outer joins, subqueries, etc... Do you think an ORM (especially NHibernate) is suitable for use in the reporting scenario described above ? Should I worry about performance for complex queries ?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this chart](http://ormbattle.net/). There is no DataObjects.Net for now, but its results in comparison to EF and NHibernate are shown [here](http://code.ormbattle.net/#&&target=Output-DO.txt).

LINQ test code for EF is [here](http://code.ormbattle.net/#&&target=Tests%2fLinq%2fEFTest.generated.cs); versions for other tools can be found in the same folder. All these .cs files are generated by [a single T4 template](http://code.ormbattle.net/#&&target=Tests%2fLinq%2fLinqTests.tt), so tests are fully identical. Model used there is Northwind.

Few more links:

- [LINQ test description](http://ormbattle.net/index.php/linq-implementation-tests.html)
- [FAQs](http://ormbattle.net/index.php/faqs.html).

Comment: Some other links : http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/09/why-don-choose-nhibernate.html and http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/08/nhibernate-perfomance-analisys.html  :)

Comment: Alex, thanks, this site looks really promising ! Now I need to spend some time dissecting the test results ;)

Comment: Concerning complex queries: here all depends on quality of LINQ translator. NH LINQ translator seems fully straighten-forward when it works. Note that these tests show what a particular ORM _can_ translate, but not _how_. Performance tests there are designed for simple queries, so you shouldn't seriously study them. Although e.g. paging tests show some difference in quality of translation: some providers always use ROWNUMBER instead of TOP, and this is the main reason they loose on this test.

Comment: Concerning Fabio's posts: actually I commented them in ORMBattle.NET blog. His comparison was not honest at all: http://ormbattle.net/index.php/blog/105-a-honest-comparison-of-entity-framework-and-nhibernate.html

Comment: Well, as much as I'd like to, I won't be able to use EF on this project, so the comparison between EF and NH is not really relevant for me... Anyway, I think the only way to get relevant performance data for my particular scenario is to do my own tests with the actual queries my application will be doing...

Comment: Yes, that's most likely the only exit. LINQ translation has lots of aspects, so it seems almost impossible to compare the quality of translation "in general".

Comment: Is there a more recent version of the chart? A lot can be achieved in that time.

Answer (score 6):

NHibernate has a bit of a learning curve, but it is well worth learning as any time spent will pay off many times over.  I would recommend NHibernate in Action book for learning as it is an excellent resource and covers everything your question asks and a whole lot more.

NHibernate performance can be tuned (see links below) and NHibernate has robust caching mechanism.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/NHibernate_Perf.aspx
https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/performance.html

Ultimately the performance will be determined by who writes the queries as it is in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this looks interesting

Comment: I would also mention the screencast series "Summer of NHibernate" - the single reason that I'm using it today!  Steve Bohlen does a great job walking through every detail of NHibernate! http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for ORM with comprehensive and efficient LINQ translator, I recommend you to try [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) or [DataObjects.Net](http://dataobjects.net). I'm not sure about Oracle Lite support. NHibernate's LINQ translator is not fully finished yet.

Anyway the best thing you can do now is to download leading ORM tools and test them on tricky queries with grouping, joining, subqueries etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately EF is not an option (although it would have been my first choice). There are EF providers for Oracle (Devart, DataDirect), but not for Oracle Lite, and there will probably never be one because Oracle Lite isn't widely used. And DataObjects.Net apparently doesn't support Oracle yet...